# Deleting range of cells based on criterea

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have an Excel file with several macros, used for data processing.
The masterfile reads one or more .csv files and copies all data it needs into a tab (lets call it sheet1) within the masterfile. After some processing, the fresh data is copied into a second tab (sheet2) and sheet1 is cleared. Sheet2 contains all data that has been read out before.

Column F of sheet1 contains a date for a specific event, which is transferred to Column E in sheet2.
What I'd like to do is check for overlapping dates between the sheets and delete the rows containing them, so there are no double entries in sheet2.

Comment: I'm lost. If it copies from `Sheet1 Col F` into `Sheet2 Col E` that you don't want to see any duplicates. In what 2 columns should there be no repeated dates? Which column should have the dates removed?

Comment: I guess that since Sheet1 is cleared, the deletion should be done on Sheet2..

Comment: Like kenkh said, the rows containing double dates should be removed on sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the VBA so that instead of copying all the data from sheet1 into sheet2, it only copies the data that you need. Each time you're going to copy data from sheet1 to sheet2, check whether the data already exists in sheet2, and if it does, don't bother copying it. You'll need separate indexes for the rows in sheet1 and sheet2.

How much VBA do you know? How do you determine if two dates are 'overlapping'?

Comment: Unfortunately, my understanding and skills in VBA are very limited. I am able to understand the code, but am not familiar with the specific functions available. Hence I will not be able to write my own vba, except with help from the record button.

Comment: @Dincky Can you post the existing VBA, and also explain what you mean by "Overlapping" or "Double dates"?